# Android issue : More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libcrypto.so'

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

```
   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcrypto.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libssl.so'

        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libssl.so'

        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libcrypto.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libssl.so'

        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libcrypto.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libssl.so'
    }
```

I tried a lot but I am getting constantly this error cannot understand the reason behind that and due to this cannot run my application

Comment: Just delete the assembly; it seems to be built (else it probably wouldn't exist twice).

Comment: Ok thanks! Will try @MartinZeitler